# Где хранятся "magic numbers" в Си?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int foo = 5;
    if (foo == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Я понимаю где хранятся локальные, глобальные переменные. Статические данные. Инициализированные и не инициализированные. `stack, heap, .bss, .text` сегменты.

Что на счет так называемых *magic numbers*. `1` в моем примере?

Когда идет сравнение таких указателей:

```
if (sbrk_returned_val == (void*)-1)
```

то второй указатель, это указатель - который указывает на область в памяти, где хранится `-1`.

Comment: При приведенном вами сравнении указателей нет никакой ячейки памяти, где хранится эта `-1`... Здесь просто значение `-1` интерпретируется как значение указателя. Такие числа обычно просто хранятся в самом коде - типа `mov eax, [foo]`, `cmp eax,1` или как-то так...

Comment: @Harry т.е. в .text сегменте получается? Если не stack, heap, .bss.

Comment: Я бы не назвал это "хранением". Вы никак не получите указатель, указывающий на эту величину. По крайней мере, в рамках С++. Да и в рамках ассемблера это проблематично, в особенности в чем-то типа `i = i + 1` :)

Comment: @Harry другими словами, `(void*)-1` - это `void* bar = -1;` неявно?

Comment: Боюсь я ответить - напутаю в терминах, знатоки стандарта съедят без соли и без лука, как аборигены Кука :)

Comment: Переведите название вопроса также, пожалуйста

Comment: @Tracy, да, семантика та же самая, только наоборот: `(void*)-1` — это явное приведение типа, а `void* bar = -1;` — неявное.

Answer (score 3):

Где будут храниться явные константы и будут ли вообще - зависит от реализации и от контекста.

- Во-первых, константы могут вообще нигде не храниться, а вместо этого "растворяться" в коде. Очевидный пример - константа `0`. Можно сказать, что в большинстве случаев манипуляции с `0` реализуются через процессорные инструкции, никак не содержащие явной работы с `0`. То же самое можно сказать про многие другие "часто встречающиеся" константы, вроде `1` или `-1`.

  Константа `3`, использованная для задания количества итераций цикла, может исчезнуть из кода, если цикл будет развернут в буквальное троекратное повторение кода своего тела.

  Умножение на `2` может быть заменено на сдвиг на `1` и наоборот.

  Говорить о *хранении* чего-то, что не является lvalue бессмысленно. Оно в общем случае нигде не хранится.
- Во-вторых, когда в финальном коде константа таки "выживает" в более-менее явном виде, то все зависит от возможностей аппаратной платформы по встраиванию таких констант непосредственно в инструкции процессора. Если константу можно встроить в инструкцию процессора, то она как правило будет встроена, т.е. в "памяти данных" ее храниться не будет. Она будет фактически "храниться" в сегменте кода. В противном случае, т.е. когда встраивание невозможно, такая константа действительно будет храниться в сегменте инициализированных данных как некая переменная с внутренним именем.

  Например, на платформе x86 целочисленные константы обычно встраиваются в инструкции процессора, а плавающие константы хранятся в сегменте инициализированных данных.

---

В вашем примере `(void*)-1` - это не "это указатель - который указывает на область в памяти, где хранится -1". С чего бы это вдруг? Результат приведения целочисленного значения к указательному типу определяется реализацией, но обычно в данном случае вы получите "указатель -1", а не "указатель на -1". Внутреннее представление указателей, однако, обычно рассматривают как беззнаковые целочисленные значения.

Comment: Не совсем понял фразы, "_Указатель -1_". Это что-то определенное стандартом? В оригинале, "pointer to a memory address". Я не могу представить себе _pointer -1_. Никогда раньше с подобным не встречался. Так же не понял смысла, "растворяется в коде". Поправьте если я не прав, но это больше похоже на довод. Если таких констант будет N в коде, то это в любом случае будет нагружать хоть какой-то сегмент, поэтому я думаю, что они все таки где-то хранятся, в каком-то из секторов. Поправьте, если я где-то серьезно ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Tracy, `"растворяются в коде"` -- это означает, что такие константы являются частью одной (или нескольких) машинных инструкций

Comment: @Tracy: Вы написали `a = 0`, а компилятор сгенерировал процессорную команду `xor rax, rax`. Где в таком случае хранится константа `0`?

Comment: @AnT поправь если ошибаюсь. .text сегмент, это сегмент - где хранится код программы. Не прав?

Comment: @Tracy: Да, правильно, в коде программы. Но суть в том, что константы `0` в явном виде в этом коде уже нет вообще. Она "растворилась" в коде.

Comment: @Tracy, не нужно привязываться так к именам секций - они могут вообще произвольным образом называться. И вообще все (кроме заголовка) может находиться в одной секции - и код, и изменяемые данные, и импорты